# Animate simple javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, animation, slideshow

I made a simple slideshow on my [website](http://donie-webdesign.de/) and would now like to animate it. I just want the images to fade into one another. I would prefer not to use jQuery, as this is probably the only js I will need on my website. jQuery would be okay though, if it is necessary.

Preloading the images (in website head)

```
<!--
var image1=new Image;image1.src="images/referenzen/besten-weine.jpg";var image2=new         Image;image2.src="images/referenzen/pixelization.jpg";var image3=new  Image;image3.src="images/referenzen/immo-buerk.jpg"
//-->
```

Code in slideshow position (image src is then changed by the script)

```
 <a href="javascript:slidelink()"><img src="images/referenzen/besten-weine.jpg" name="slide" width="445px" height="300px"></a>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                <!--
                var step=1
                //a variable that will keep track of the image currently being displayed.
                var whichimage=1
                function slideit(){
                if (!document.images)
                return
                document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
                whichimage=step
                if (step<3)
                step++
                else
                step=1
                setTimeout("slideit()",4000)
                }
                slideit()
                function slidelink(){
                if (whichimage==1)
                window.location="#weine"
                else if (whichimage==2)
                window.location="#mc"
                else if (whichimage==3)
                window.location="#immo"
                }
                //-->
            </script>
```

I can do some CSS animations but am new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="image-front"><img src="photo1.png" /></div>
    <div class="image-back"><img src="photo2.png" /></div>
</div>
```

You can do:

```
.slideshow .image-front {
    transition: .5s;
    transition-property: opacity;
}
.slideshow.transition .image-front {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Then after `.5` seconds swap the image in `image-back` to `image-front`.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div>
        <a href="#"><img src="back.png" title="back" id="back"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="next.png" title="next" id="next"></a>
</div>

<img src="image1.png" id="image1" />
<img src="image2.png" id="image2" />
<img src="image3.png" id="image3" />
```

Jquery and javascript:

Global Variable:

```
var actual = 1;
```

To go to next image:

```
$('#next').click(function(){    
    $('img').stop(true, true);
    $('#image' + _actual).fadeOut(function(){
        actual++;
        if(actual > 3){
         actual = 1;
        }
        $('#image' + actual).fadeIn();          
    });
});
```

To go to previos image:

```
$('#back').click(function(){    
    $('img').stop(true, true);
    $('#image' + _actual).fadeOut(function(){
        actual--;
        if(actual == 0){
         actual = 3;
        }
        $('#image' + actual).fadeIn();          
    });
});
```

I just wrote this, haven´t test it, but i think that works.

Comment: It unfortunately doesnt work. Youz can look at it on my website. http://donie-webdesign.de Thanks for the work you put in though. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Looking at your site it looks like the global variable _actual is missing. Please check if you are creating this variable globaly, and dont forget to initalize it with value 1.

Comment: where would i set the var _actual ? In the same script as for the buttons or in the head or where?